# Run a parameterized query/command asynchronously?

Tags: c#, sql, asynchronous

How could I take the following code and make each iteration of myValues asynchronous (in regards to executing the command, not the loop itself)?

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add("@myParameter", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    foreach(string myValue in myValues)
    {
        command.Parameters["@myParameter"].Value = myValue;
        using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You may want to put code into a backgroundworker so you can perform other tasks while updating is occuring.

Comment: @jdweng There's no reason to use a BGW if you do the work using inherently asynchronous IO operations.  There's no CPU bound work here.

Comment: @David I tried that and got an error about an async already running.  Either I used it wrong or it's not suited for this case.

Comment: I've never seen an async used with an SQLConnection.

Comment: @ATD: Certainly sounds like you used it wrong, because I don't see how using the async method isn't suited for an asynchronous operation.  I would recommend going back to that error and correcting the problem.

Comment: @David the error wasn't with me using it asynchronously, but rather that I wasn't awaiting ExecuteReaderAsync each iteration.  When it got to the next iteration of the loop, ExecuteReaderAsync threw an exception.  It appeared that I would have to either await each iteration or use multiple instances of SqlCommand (both of which don't suit my needs).

Comment: @ATD: Well, yes, if you don't await the result and attempt to perform the next operation before the last one has completed then that could certainly cause an error.  It's not clear at a high level what your needs are, but the for the small code sample in the question one would simply use the `async` operations and `await` them.  It sounds like the asynchronous nature of what you're attempting to do is on a somewhat different scale than what's presented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    UpdateValues();
}

async Task UpdateValues()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your_connection_string_here"))
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("your_sql_statement_here", connection))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            command.Parameters.Add("@myParameter", SqlDbType.VarChar);

            foreach (string myValue in myValues)
            {
                command.Parameters["@myParameter"].Value = myValue;

                var dr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
                while (await dr.ReadAsync())
                {
                    // do your thing here //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @David, explain why. Your comment don't say anything useful. (it could be async Task instead)

Comment: Because the method can't be awaited, so there's no way for consuming code to await it or observe the result of the operation.  The only reason C# even *allows* `async void` was for backward compatibility with old UI-event technologies which *must* return `void`.  (This was very likely a sore point for the C# language team.)  And even then needs to be used *very* carefully.

Comment: If you are using a data reader you really should be using `while (await dr.ReadAsync())` too. Also `await connection.OpenAsync();` would not hurt either in the event you need to wait for the connection to time out for a failed connection.

Comment: it's true, so, I'll change the answer,

Comment: @RossanoSzczepanski not quite what I'm looking for.  I'd like to be executing the next iteration of the reader BEFORE the previous one finishes.